# Sort Vector in a Map c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, dictionary

I'm trying to sort some vectors inside my map, but when I run the program I have a Segmentation Fault.

```
typedef map<int, vector<int> > Map;
Map m;
for (Map::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
  sort(it->second.begin(), it->second.end());
}
```

Just before the sort I have a section that insert datas:

```
int x = 2;
int y = 3;
map<int, vector<int> >::iterator itTemp;

itTemp = FontaneMapX.find(x);
if (itTemp == m.end())
    itTemp = m.insert(make_pair(x,vector<int>())).first;
itTemp->second.push_back(y);
```

I don't remove/add items after this section, not event to the vectors inside the map.

Any ideas on what I should change?

Comment: I ran your code here http://ideone.com/wBKuDP and it didn't segfault. That's not conclusive, it may just work by chance. But I can't see anything wrong with the code, so perhaps something else is causing the error.

Comment: Btw you can also do this which may be clearer: `vector<int>& vec = m[x]; if (vec.empty()) vec.push_back(y);` It creates the value with default constructor if it didn't exist.

Comment: @Neil No need for the `if (vec.empty())` test, it doesn’t occur in OP’s code either. Just do `m[x].push_back(y);` – one line instead of four. ;-)

Comment: I can't see an immediate reason why this shouldn't work. [This example](http://ideone.com/0wBPX2) isn't spot-on with yours, but clearly demonstrates there no nothing wrong with sorting the vector in the `second` of your map pair.

Comment: Check the map/vectors aren't being accessed from another thread at the same time? Check you don't have your own `sort` function that's being called instead of `std::sort`?

Comment: Mind showing a bit more code? I don't see anything wrong with what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

see this implementation works well i guess
(http://ideone.com/QACBSZ)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

map<int ,vector<int> > mp;
map<int, vector<int> >::iterator it;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int m;
        cin >> m;
        vector <int> v(m);
        
        for(int j=0; j < m; j++)
            cin >> v[j];
        
        for(int j=0; j < m; j++)
            cout << v[j] << " ";
        
        cout << endl;
    
        mp.insert(make_pair(i,v));
    }

    for(it = mp.begin(); it != mp.end(); it++)
        sort(it->second.begin(), it->second.end());
    

    for(it = mp.begin(); it != mp.end(); it++){
        int l = it->second.size();
        cout << it->first << "th sorted array-> ";
        
        for(int j = 0; j < l; j++)
            cout << it->second[j] << " ";
        
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your program is producing a segmentation fault BEFORE sorting, at the insertion phase.

```
map<int, vector<int> >::iterator itTemp;
itTemp = FontaneMapX.find(x);  // should be m.find(x)?
if (itTemp == m.end())
    itTemp = m.insert(make_pair(x,vector<int>())).first;
itTemp->second.push_back(y);
```

The segmentation fault occurs if `itTemp` is set to `m.end()` by the `find(x)` function call.  In that case, trying to call `itTemp->second.push_back(y)` causes a segfault.

That section should be

```
itTemp = FontaneMapX.find(x);
if (itTemp == m.end())
{
    itTemp = m.insert(make_pair(x,vector<int>())).first;
    itTemp->second.push_back(y);
}
```

Or better,

```
itTemp = FontaneMapX.find(x);
if (itTemp == m.end())
{
    // Insert a vector with one element.
    itTemp = m.insert(std::make_pair(x,vector<int>(/*count*/1, y)));
}
```

Or using C++11,

```
itTemp = FontaneMapX.find(x);
if (itTemp == m.end())
{
    // Insert a vector with one element.
    itTemp = m.insert(std::make_pair(x, std::vector<int>({y})));  // use initializer list
}
```